# Initialize an array of reference_wrapper

Tags: c++, reference-wrapper

Coming from C to C++, I'm trying to understand the world of smart pointers & references. I've got the following:

```
class Game {
public:
    ...
private:
    ...
    static GamePiece EmptyPiece;
    reference_wrapper<GamePiece> _board[N][M] = { ref(Game::EmptyPiece) };
    vector<GamePlayer> _players = vector<GamePlayer>(N_PLAYERS, GamePlayer());
    ...
};
```

In the following situation, I would like each `Player` to hold a `vector<GamePiece>` and return references to these pieces, and put then in the `_board`. However, the following initialization of my `_board` yields

> no default constructor exists for class "std::reference_wrapper

What am I missing here? In terms of ownership, each `GamePlayer` is owned by the `Game` (as can be seen), and the `GamePiece`s are definitely owned by the `GamePlayer`s, and that's why I want to use references.

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's this here

```
reference_wrapper<GamePiece> _board[N][M] = { ref(Game::EmptyPiece) };
```

You initialize the first element (with some brace elision thrown in) but leave the rest default initialized. Which can't happen, since `std::reference_wrapper` cannot be default initialized (just like the reference it models).

You can substitute the raw array for a `std::vector` of `N*M` size, and use the appropriate constructor which will copy initialize all the elements (like you do for `_players`). Of course, you'll need to do the calculations for indexing by yourself, but the memory will be laid out sequentially.

Comment: I though it initialized the entire array - thanks. Is there a better container than a `vector`, where the notion of the dimensions is still clear?

Comment: @galah92 - You can use a vector of vectors in a pinch. But I think a flat memory layout is better. The logical dimensions of the board don't mean it should have physical dimensions. But if you want to easily access via logical dimensions, you can wrap the vector in a [small type that offers that appropriate `operator()`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op).

Comment: @galah92 you can use a `std::array` of `std::array` if you know the size at compile time

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot - That doesn't escape the problem of needing to initialize all the elements to prevent their default initialization. It's just cleaner than a 2d raw array.

Comment: @StoryTeller ah yes, true.

Answer (score 1):

Initializing an array of references is pain in my opinion. The problem is -- as said in the answer by @StoryTeller -- that a `reference_wrapper` is not default constructible.

So you have to write your own workaround functions. I'll post code for the general problem of initializing an array of references and won't dive deeply into your question.

So consider the following case: you have an array `arr` holding elements of some type (e.g. a `Game` as in your question) that supports `operator[]`. You want an array of const- or non-const references to elements in this array specified by the indices `ind`. Here you go:

```
template<typename arr_t, size_t ... I>
auto get_const_reference_array(arr_t const& arr, std::array<size_t, sizeof ...(I)> const& ind, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    using T = std::decay_t<decltype(std::declval<arr_t>().operator[](size_t{}))>;
    return std::array<std::reference_wrapper<const T>, sizeof ...(I)> { std::cref(arr[std::get<I>(ind)]) ... };
}
template<typename arr_t, size_t dim>
auto get_const_reference_array(arr_t const& arr, std::array<size_t, dim> const& ind)
{
    return get_const_reference_array(arr, ind, std::make_index_sequence<dim>{});
}
```

For the non-const version, remove all `const`'s in this code and replace `std::cref` by `std::ref`.

Use it as

```
std::array<int,5> arr{{1,3,5,7,9}};
std::array<size_t,2> ind{{1,3}};
auto ref_arr = get_const_reference_array(arr, ind);

std::vector<int> vec{{1,3,5,7,9}};
auto ref_vec = get_const_reference_array(vec, ind);
```

`ref_arr` then is an array of size `2` which holds const references to `arr[1]` and `arr[3]`, and the same for the vector (note however that references to a vector are in general not stable, i.e. by resizing or similar actions they might get invalidated).